# MLP with both Pattern Recognition & Forecasting Inputs: Bad Idea?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

This is regarding a 3-layer MLP (Input, Hidden, Output) in Ward Systems NeuroShell 2

I would prefer to split these input layer classes (PR & F) into 2 separate nets with their own hidden layers that then feed a single output layer - this would be a 3 layer network.  There could be a 4 layer version using a new hidden layer to combine the 2 nets:

1) Inputs (partitioned into F and PR classes)
2) Hiddens (partitioned into F and PR classes)
3) Hiddens (fully connected "mixing" layer)
4) Output

These structures would be trained at once as opposed to training the two networks, getting the output/prediction, and then averaging those 2 numbers.

I've found that while averaging outputs works, "letting a net do it" works even better.  But this requires layer partitioning which my platform (NeuralShell 2) cannot.  And I've never read a paper where anyone attempts to do better than averaging.

FYI the ratio of PR to F inputs is 10:1.

Most discussion of nets is Forecasting with usually is of the Order of 10 inputs.  Pattern Recognition has Orders more, 100's to 1000's and even more.

In fact, it seems that the two types of problems are virtually mutually exclusive when searching the research.

So my conclusion is having both types of structure in a single network is probably a very bad idea.

Agreed?

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad idea at all! In fact this approach is a very common one that is used very frequently, you just missed out on some secret lingo.

Basically, what you're trying to do here is an ensemble prediction. The best way to approach this is to train two entirely separate nets for both halves of your problem. Then use those outputs as inputs to a new neural network.

The field is known as [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) and the results are often quite good.

As far as your question of blending pattern recognition and forecasting, well it's really impossible to make a call on that without knowing more specifics around the data you're working with, but just because people haven't tried it doesn't mean you shouldn't either.

Comment: Thanks for the ensemble learning definition - I've definitely run into it quite often but there are so many termed strategies, I simply can't keep them straight.
<p>
With NS2, the is probably the only way to handle this approach.

What interests me is a platform that would let me train together the 2 class nets AND the ensemble.  MemBrain allows ANY connectivity AND recursion loops AND has scripting language - but I'm delaying a platform change as long as possible.

Actually, rather than averaging, the ensemble approach should be better.  However it adds many steps to do a prediction.

Comment: Don't use membrain. Recent literature has shown very conclusively that  increased model size rather than added complexity is the true path to performance. If you think you need the added complexity you're probably making things more complicated than they have to be. Also, if an answer is helpful don't forget to accept it (the green check mark under the vote count)

Comment: "Increased Model Size" does this mean run extra large numbers of hidden nodes (3 layer MLP) and use early stopping or regularization, etc. to avoid overtraining?

Comment: @user5070630 a combination of larger numbers of hidden nodes and more hidden layers.

Answer (score 0):

forecasting using time series creates a sliding window of data sequences for input into the network.   I don't think you show mix forecasting with classification.  The output is for classification can be either a softmax or a binary result.  Whereas the output of a forecast will be a dense output with one neuron.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-multilayer-perceptron-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

```
 [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

 X,             y
 10, 20, 30     40
 20, 30, 40     50
 30, 40, 50     60
```

The input X and y is then fit by the multi layer perceptron.